# How to export a renderscript project to a SDK including jar and so libs

Tags: android, renderscript

I wrote an android project with renderscript. And now I want to export part of this project to a SDK including jar libs and .so libs without revealing any renderscript codes. Is there any way to accomplish that?

To help you understanding my question more clearly:

(1) In my source project, .rs files are listed as raw files:

[image]

(2) But I don't want these rs files to be added in my SDK. Give that I can get the .so libs in the bin\rsLibs directory：

[image]

So, can I use these .so libs directly other than the .rs raw files?